# Django form test generates error with a foreign key model field

Tags: python, django, testing

Have a problem testing a filed form. In field that is defined with **models.ForeignKey** the test generates an error.

The field **gender_opt** is defined in **models.py** as

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    gender_opt = models.ForeignKey(GenderOption, null=False, blank=False)
```

with ForeignKey given by

```
class GenderOption(models.Model):
    gender_txt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In my forms.py I have

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Patient

fields = [
         other fields
        'gender_opt'
    ]

widgets = {
other widgets

'gender_opt': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'gender_id', 'required': "",
                                     'data-error': "Gender must be filled"}),
}
```

and my **test.py** is

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

class FormValidation(TestCase):
def test_patient_add_ok(self):
    """test save patient data successfuly"""

    data = {u'cpf_id': [u'248.215.628-98'], u'state_txt': [u'RJ'], 
            u'citizenship_txt': [u'BR'], u'name_txt': [u'Test pacient'],
            u'date_birth_txt': [u'15/01/2003'], u'country_txt': [u'BR'],
            u'gender_opt': [u'1']}


    response = self.client.post('/quiz/patient/new/', data)
    errors = response.context['patient_form'].errors
```

In **errors**, I got the follow message:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

The URL '/quiz/patient/new/' in **test.py** points to the view (in views.py)

```
def patient_create(request, template_name="quiz/register.html"):

   gender_options = GenderOption.objects.all()

   patient_form = PatientForm()

if request.method == "POST":

    patient_form = PatientForm(request.POST)

    if patient_form.is_valid():
        new_patient = patient_form.save(commit=False)
        new_patient.save()



context = {'patient_form': patient_form,
           'gender_options': gender_options,
}

return render(request, template_name, context)
```

I suppose the problem is models.ForeignKey field type.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you definitely have a `gender_opt` with `id=1` in the test database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create a `GenderOption` object. Also, you don't actually need to make a request using `self.client` while you are testing a form:

```
class FormValidation(TestCase):
    def test_patient_add_ok(self):
        """test save patient data successfully"""

        # create GenderOption
        gender_opt = GenderOption.objects.create(gender_txt='M')

        data = {u'cpf_id': [u'248.215.628-98'], u'state_txt': [u'RJ'], 
                u'citizenship_txt': [u'BR'], u'name_txt': [u'Test pacient'],
                u'date_birth_txt': [u'15/01/2003'], u'country_txt': [u'BR'],
                u'gender_opt': [str(gender_opt.id)]}

        form = PatientForm(data=data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        ...
```